How to efficiently handle Keycloak token refresh in a React app using @react-keycloak/web?
I am using Keycloak for authentication and authorization in a React app. On the React side, I am utilizing the keycloak.js and @react-keycloak/web packages to manage the tokens. Here's how I have integrated Keycloak into my app:
function App() {
  return (
    <ReactKeycloakProvider
      authClient={client}
      initOptions={{
        onLoad: "login-required",
      }}
    >
      <MainApp />
    </ReactKeycloakProvider>
  );
}

I understand that Keycloak doesn't store tokens in client-side storage, and we can access the token through the Keycloak object like this:
import { useKeycloak } from "@react-keycloak/web";
const { keycloak, initialized } = useKeycloak();
const token = keycloak.token;

This Keycloak object contains both the access and refresh token. I also know that when the access token expires, we should use the refresh token to get a new access token for a seamless user experience.
However, I have some doubts and issues with token management in my app:
1. Token Object Reload on Full Page Refresh:
When the whole app initially loads, it retrieves an object with both the access and refresh tokens. As the user navigates between pages, this object remains the same. But when the user reloads the app (e.g., by clicking the refresh button), a new object is retrieved with new access and refresh tokens.

Is this behavior normal?

Does this impact performance, and how can I optimize it?


2. Using keycloak.updateToken(tokenMinValidity):
I also learned about the updateToken method for token renewal. Here’s how I implemented it:
try {
  await keycloak.updateToken(30); // 30 seconds before token expiry
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Failed to refresh token:', error);
}


What does the value passed to updateToken (e.g., 30) represent?

Does this method use the refresh token to get a new access token? If so, why don't we need to pass the refresh token explicitly?


3. My Implementation of Token Refresh in React:
I tried implementing token refresh in my React app using useEffect. Here’s the code:
import { useKeycloak } from "@react-keycloak/web";

const { keycloak, initialized } = useKeycloak();

useEffect(() => {
  const refreshToken = async () => {
    if (keycloak) {
      try {
        if (keycloak.token) {
          if (keycloak.tokenParsed && keycloak.tokenParsed.exp) {
            const expiresIn = keycloak.tokenParsed.exp * 1000 - Date.now();
            const refreshThreshold = 60 * 1000; // 1 minute in milliseconds

            if (expiresIn < refreshThreshold) {
              await keycloak.updateToken(60)
                .then((refreshed) => {
                  if (refreshed) {
                    console.log("New access token", keycloak.token);
                  } else {
                    console.log("Token is still valid");
                  }
                })
                .catch(() => {
                  console.error("Failed to refresh the token");
                });
            } else {
              setRefreshTimeout(expiresIn - refreshThreshold);
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error refreshing token:", error);
      }
    }
  };

  const setRefreshTimeout = (timeout = 60 * 1000) => {
    if (keycloak.tokenParsed && keycloak.tokenParsed.exp) {
      const expiresIn = keycloak.tokenParsed.exp * 1000 - Date.now();
      const refreshThreshold = 60 * 1000;
      const timeoutId = setTimeout(
        refreshToken,
        expiresIn - refreshThreshold
      );
      return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }
  };

  if (initialized) {
    refreshToken();
  }
}, [keycloak, initialized]);

This function successfully refreshes the token, but I noticed that after the refresh, I receive a new object containing both a new access token and a new refresh token.

Why am I getting a new refresh token when only the access token should be refreshed?

Is this implementation correct, or can it be optimized further?



Any guidance or clarification on these points would be greatly appreciated!
